# Calculating linguistic diversity of a text with respect to size

Tags: methodology, diversity

I'm doing linguistics work and I'm trying to make a measure of linguistic diversity in a text. A simple calculation seems to be

linguistic uniformity ( or diversity) = number of words / unique words

But this must "privilege" shorter texts like poetry for diversity, since the author is less likely to repeat themselves in so short a space. For example, Blake's poetry gets a score of 5, whereas the KJV bible scores 79 and this has a lot to do with the size of the bible compared to Blake's poetry. If we analysed more of the Blakes's corpus, his score would definitely go higher.

How can I normalize the calculation, taking into account the inevitable repetition that comes with longer texts, and the fact that shorter texts are so small that we just haven't seen an appreciable part of an author's lexicon? I know that there's a name for this, I just can't remember what it is. I've looked at the wiki article on diversity index but it has not helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are other measures of diversity that are invariant to the data size (in theory), and you may want to consider. One is **Shannon's entropy** defined as:

$ H = - \sum_i p_i \log_2 p_i $

where $p_i$ is the probability of the word indexed by $i$. Entropy quantifies *how concentrated your distribution is*. Most of your words would be 'the', 'of', 'and', 'a', and the proportion of these words should not be highly variable as a function of text length. However, the uncommon words in your text may have a different proportions. If the author uses more diverse vocabulary, the entropy is going to be higher. In the extreme case, if the author uses all words with an equally frequent manner, it would have the maximum entropy (very unlikely that this would happen, of course).

**Estimating entropy** could be tricky, and there are many methods available. One of which is described in [my humble paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0328). We estimate the entropy of the word frequencies in Moby Dick (figure 9).

Comment: Thanks. I've also just found this paper, which addresses the problem: http://vli-journal.org/issues/01.1/issue01.1.10.pdf

Comment: @Tennant Side note: entropy would be impossible to estimate for short sentences.